# How do I configure PyTest to read .toml instead of .conf?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery

I'm having a hard time navigating Pytest's documentation on top of keeping up with legacy code architecture. What's a good/best practice for parsing a config file through Pytest? I want to switch us over to .toml because it's more Pythonic and Pytest itself uses .toml instead of .conf

Resources to reproduce my own errors:
https://readthedocs.io

Comment: PEP-518 support is not implemented yet, see [issue #1556](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1556).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Will read up on this.